# MVC3 load start up page error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-config, visual-studio-2012

Ok, So as a company we deployed our first MVC3 application on a web server. Which has been set up to handle .NET

The server uses Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.

However when we point the browser to the URL we receive this error.

**Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.**

When we point it to a known path such as:

```
http://websitename/subfolder/subfolder/Views
```

We get the same error. Clearly when ww try to go directly to the Razor page, for example:

```
http://websitename/subfolder/subfolder/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml
```

As you would expect it downloads the .cshtml file, because the browser can't read .cshtml, it reads the generated .html.

if I point to:

```
http://websitename/subfolder/subfolder/Views/Pages/Index.html
```

It cant find anything.

It works running on localhost through Visual Studio. and when published the start up page is just the root and it runs and directs to the correct place through VS.

My question is how do you point to the generated html on a web server manually, or is there a reason it isn't finding the start page when I just go to the root on the server?

I have check the IIS and made sure that the correct things are set to local copy 'true', and I have also added runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=”true” to my web.config file.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Server-OS and IIS you are using?

Comment: using IIS6? read this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: we are using Windows Server 2008 and iis 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't installed .NET 4.
Please can you clarify your server settings, such as OS, IIS version, etc?

Comment: Clarified in Original post at the top.

Comment: Is .NET 4 installed, since you are using mvc3?

Comment: Just checked then and on the server its asp.net 3.5, is this the problem?

Comment: Please check all projects in your solution and make sure they all target .NET 3.5. Also, create a simple Test.aspx page (without code behind) and add it to the root of your website. Then try to browse it and make sure it's displayed correctly. If it's not, then there is a problem with IIS not enabling .NET pages. Make sure you add some C#/VB.net code to your .ASPX file, like WriteLine just to ensure IIS is actually processing the page.

Comment: As I understood it, Razor won't work on anything less than ASP.NET 4, so I just figured the project was moot?

Answer (score 2):

In MVC you don't access the views via the browser, you access actions on the controller, and they in turn return a view.

So you should be trying to access

```
http://websitename/controller/action
```

The controller part is the name of a controller with the "controller" bit lobbed off the end, e.g. to access a Login action on the AccountController you would go to

```
http://websitename/Account/Login
```

You're actions should be defined something like this in your controllers

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
```

Comment: Ok, so I have a controller called PagesController.cs, and as its a CRUD it has a 'Edit' action. However when I try to access http://www.websitename/subfolder/subfolder/Pages/Edit I do not get that error, but instead get a 'this Page cannot be found' 404 page.

Comment: is websitename/subfolder/subfolder the root of your application? normally it would be just websitename/. Sorting out 404s is dependent on the IIS version so one of the other answers may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the requests are not going from the IIS to the ASP.Net runtime. This is configured differently (or doen't need to be at all) depending on the version of IIS you are using (which also depends on Server-OS you are using). On some older versions of IIS (eg. Version) in MVC-Routing you have to add a .aspx (or any other extension) to all your routes (see Global.asax) and then configure IIS to route all the .aspx requests to the ASP.Net subsystem. Newer versions of IIS don't need all of this.

The following tutorial from MS may help:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs